# Помогите поправить программу с сигналами. Qt 5.10

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcreator

Добрый вечер.
Возникла проблема с сигналами.
Нужно передать данные с Form, на MainWindow. Без дополнительной формы всё реализовано, но не понятно, как соединить две вместе.

Помогите, пожалуйста.
Заранее извиняюсь за быдлокод.

Не могу правильно вставить код сюда, поэтому ссылка на скачивание: [тык](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1w7qZVByQNWqA45cx0upVvGAXP3l6BVoH)

[image: mainwindow]

[image: form]

### mainwindow.h

```
public slots:
    void recieveData(QString str);

private slots:

    void on_ResultButton_clicked();

    void on_EnterDataButton_clicked();
```

### form.h

```
signals:
    void sendData(QString str);

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();
    void onButtonSend();

public:
    explicit Form(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Form();
```

### form.cpp

```
void Form::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    connect(this, SIGNAL(sendData(QString)), mainwindow, 
SLOT(recieveData(QString)));
}

void Form::onButtonSend()
{
    QString str_DataEditForm (ui -> dateEditForm -> text());
    ui -> HBDay -> setText(str_DataEditForm);
    emit sendData(ui -> HBDay -> text());
    connect(ui -> pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, 
SLOT(onButtonSend()));
}
```

### mainwindow.cpp

```
void MainWindow::recieveData(QString str)
{
    connect(myform, SIGNAL(sendData(QString)), this, SLOT(recieveData(QString)));
    QString data = str;
    ui -> HBDay -> setText(data);
}

    void MainWindow::on_EnterDataButton_clicked()
{
    connect(ui->EnterDataButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), myform, SLOT(show()));
}
```

Comment: Ну можно банально передать данные в конструкторе Form

Answer (score 0):

Вот работающий вариант:
Ссылка для скачивания [готовый исходный код](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1a6wUWKk9cYyb54v8KUTGwWUvGdqMVCi2)

**form.h**

```
#ifndef FORM_H
#define FORM_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QDate>

namespace Ui {
class Form;
}

class Form : public QWidget
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
explicit Form(QWidget *parent = 0);
~Form();

signals:
void sigSetDateTime(QDate);

private slots:
void slotSetDateTime();

private:
Ui::Form *ui;
};

#endif // FORM_H
```

**form.cpp**

```
#include "form.h"
#include "ui_form.h"
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QDateEdit>
#include <QDebug>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

Form::Form(QWidget *parent) :
QWidget(parent),
ui(new Ui::Form)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this,     SLOT(slotSetDateTime()));
}

Form::~Form()
{
delete ui;
}

void Form::slotSetDateTime()
{
//-- Создали промежуточный слот для формирования сигнала со значением дата
qDebug() << "Signal from form";
emit sigSetDateTime(ui->dateEditForm->date());
}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include "form.h"
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QStringList>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
 Q_OBJECT

public:
explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
~MainWindow();

private slots: //определение функций и кнопок
void on_ResultButton_clicked();
    void on_EnterDataButton_clicked();

private:
Ui::MainWindow *ui;
Form *myform;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QDateEdit>
#include "form.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
myform = new Form();

    //-- соединяем сигнал из формы с полем "дата" в главном окне
    connect(myform, SIGNAL(sigSetDateTime(QDate)), ui->dateEdit, SLOT(setDate(QDate)));
}

void MainWindow::on_ResultButton_clicked()
{
qint64 y;

//Вывод текущей даты
QDate currDate = QDate::currentDate();
ui -> NowTimeLabel -> setText(currDate.toString("MM/dd/yyyy"));

//Вывод введенной даты
QString str_DataEdit (ui -> dateEdit -> text());
ui -> HBDay -> setText(str_DataEdit);
QDate d = ui -> dateEdit -> date();

//Сравнение
QDate entDate(d.year(), d.month(), d.day());
y = entDate.daysTo(currDate);

//Вывод разницы между датами в label
QString y1 = QString::number(y);
ui -> DiffLabel -> setText(y1);

//Вычисление данных и их вывод
int Prospal, Morgnul, Udarov, Perekachalo, Vipito, Smeyalsya;
Prospal = 8;
Prospal = Prospal * y;
QString Prospal1 = QString::number(Prospal);
ui -> ProspalCounter -> setText(Prospal1);

Morgnul = 230137;
Morgnul = Morgnul * y;
QString Morgnul1 = QString::number(Morgnul);
ui -> MorgnulCounter -> setText(Morgnul1);

Udarov = 70000;
Udarov = Udarov * y;
QString Udarov1 = QString::number(Udarov);
ui -> UdarovCounter -> setText(Udarov1);

Perekachalo = 2000;
Perekachalo = Perekachalo * y;
QString Perekachalo1 = QString::number(Perekachalo);
ui -> PerekachaloCounter -> setText(Perekachalo1);

Vipito = 2;
Vipito = Vipito * y;
QString Vipito1 = QString::number(Vipito);
ui -> VipitoCounter -> setText(Vipito1);

Smeyalsya = 20;
Smeyalsya = Smeyalsya * y;
QString Smeyalsya1 = QString::number(Smeyalsya);
ui -> SmeyalsyaCounter -> setText(Smeyalsya1);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_EnterDataButton_clicked()
{
myform->show(); // показываем форму
}
```