# Как правильно указать главную форму в connect?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcreator

Здравствуйте.

Есть дополнительная форма form и главная форма mainwindow.

### Form.cpp

```
#include "form.h"
#include "ui_form.h"
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QDateEdit>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

Form::Form(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Form)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Form::~Form()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Form::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    connect(this, SIGNAL(sendData(QString)), mainwindow, SLOT(recieveData(QString))); 
}
```

На mainwindow ругается, что mainwindow необъявленный идентификатор. (ошибка C2065). 
На ui не реагирует, т.к. думает что это Form.

Как правильно объявить?

С уважением.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что сигнал `sendData` принадлежит `Form`?

Comment: @BeardedBeaver да, верно.

Comment: В таком случае я подозреваю, что объект класса `Form` объявлен как член класса `MainWindow`, в этом случае `connect` надо перенести собственно в `MainWindow`

Comment: @BeardedBeaver Как это узнать (что Form член класса MainWindow) и куда тогда этот коннект переносить? В mainwindow есть `connect(ui->EnterDataButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), myform, SLOT(show()));` который вызывает окно по клику на кнопку на mainwindow. В receiveData переносить коннект?

Comment: @BeardedBeaver есть [открытый вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/766308/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-qt-5-10?noredirect=1#comment1192141_766308), но там уже немного не актуально, но суть наверно будет понятна.